# Passing multiple values from the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC app, I need to load a hard coded list of values in the dropdown and pass them to the controller when the user clicks on the Cancel button.

In my view I have the following right now:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Cancellation Reason", new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Text1", Value = "Reason1" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Text2", Value = "Reason2" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Text3", Value = "Reason3" },                        
}) %> 
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick="CancelProgram('<%= Model.Id %>');"/>
```

How can I pass two values (Model.ID and value selected by the user in the dropdown) to the CancelProgram method which would in turn (in .js file) call the controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value of the DropDownList easily with jQuery with the following statement:
**$('#Cancellation_Reason').val()**
Once you have the value you can add it to the data you submit to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to populate two hidden fields and have them mapped then passed to the action.

```
<input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="value2" name="value2" value="" />


public ViewResult PostAction(string value1, string value2)
{
```